# how to deploy 64bit Windows Server 2016/IIS 10.0 using SingleInstance CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, awsdeploy, aws-visual-studio-toolkit

I need to host my app on Windows Server 2016 by using AWS.
as following adding `Container.Type = 64bit Windows Server 2016/IIS 10.0`  does not work.
here is sample CloudFormation template.

```
### Sample Deployment Config for the SingleInstance CloudFormation template
###
### To get the sample application to deploy you will need to customize the credentials settings
### (search for entries with values of YOUR_CREDENTIALS_HERE) then run the command. The configured 
### KeyPair and SecurityGroup must already exist.
###
###   awsdeploy SingleInstanceDeploymentSample.txt
###

########################
### General Settings ###
########################

### Name of the CloudFormation stack to create
StackName = MySingleInstanceStack

### Location of the web deploy archive
DeploymentPackage = AWSDeploymentSampleApp.zip

### Region to deploy to
Region = us-east-1

### Template can be 'SingleInstance' or 'LoadBalanced'.
Template = SingleInstance

### S3 bucket where the deployment materials will be stored. If this doesn't exist it will
### be created.
### NOTE: change the bucket name to be unique in S3 and owned by you.
UploadBucket = awsdeployment-us-east-1-samples

### EC2 Keypair for logging into the instance
KeyPair = default

### Account Profile registered with the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio or stored in the credentials file file found at
### <userhome-directroy>\.aws\credentials. The account profile is used to create the stack and deploy the application to S3.
AWSProfileName = YOUR_PROFILE_NAME_HERE

### AWS Access Key and Secret Key used to create the stack and deploy the application to S3 if not using account profiles.
# AWSAccessKey = YOUR_CREDENTIALS_HERE
# AWSSecretKey = YOUR_CREDENTIALS_HERE

###########################
### Template Parameters ###
###########################

Template.InstanceType = t1.micro

### This security group must exist and allow ingress on port 80.
Template.SecurityGroup = default

###   Template.AmazonMachineImage:    Custom AMI to Launch. Must have the AWS Deployment service installed.

#############################################################################################
### Environment Settings                                                                  ###
###                                                                                       ###
### These are available to the deployed application through the web.config as appSettings ###
#############################################################################################

Environment.PARAM1 = testing
Environment.PARAM2 = 123
Environment.PARAM3 =
Environment.PARAM4 =
Environment.PARAM5 =

### Access Key and Secret Key that your application uses to access AWS services.
### Best practice is to create an IAM user with just enough permissions to run
### your application, rather than use your root account credentials.

Environment.AWSAccessKey = YOUR_CREDENTIALS_HERE
Environment.AWSSecretKey = YOUR_CREDENTIALS_HERE

###########################################################
### Container settings                                  ###
###                                                     ###
### Settings on the App Domain or for the host manager. ###
###########################################################

### Container.Type is used to select the Windows Server/IIS version
### to deploy against. Valid values are:
### "64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 running IIS 7.5"
### "64bit Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8"
### Windows Server 2012/IIS 8 is the default if not specified.
# Container.Type = 
Container.TargetV2Runtime = false
Container.Enable32BitApplications = false
Container.ApplicationHealthcheckPath = /
Container.Type = 64bit Windows Server 2016/IIS 10.0
#############################
### Create Stack settings ###
#############################

### SNS Topic to send deployment messages to
Settings.SNSTopic = 

### Time to allow for creation of stack (default = 0 means no timeout)
Settings.CreationTimeout = 0

### If true, tear down the stack if deployment fails
Settings.RollbackOnFailure = false
```

---

here is error when deploying script  is run

```
Scanning configuration.
Retrieving standard template SingleInstance
Download complete
[Warning]: Failed download attempt 1: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[Warning]: Failed download attempt 2: Stream was not readable.
[Warning]: Failed download attempt 3: Stream was not readable.
Failed to parse deployment configuration file: Deployment failed during post-processing of configuration settings.
```

Comment: Can you try specifying this **64bit Windows Server 2016 v1.2.0 running IIS 10.0** as Container.Type value.

Comment: @TenorFlyy i tried "Container.Type = 64bit Windows Server 2016 v1.2.0 running IIS 10.0" too

Comment: Hmm, I can't say for sure, but this looks like some other issue, I've checked and the first line is some .net error. Is there a possibilty that there's something wrong with what's inside the zip?

Comment: i could able to deploy the server from different account. but still it creates Windows Server 2012

Comment: even above script is success . it doesn't create Windows Server 2016. it creates Windows Server 2012 .i tested